# Extracting from List

Tags: python, list, function, indexing, weighted-average

#### What I have coded

```
students = ['Rose', 'Dorothy', 'Sophia', 'Blanch']

for i in range(len(students)):
    print('Hey',students[i],',please input the folowing grades:')
    weightAvg = []
    discussionGrade = int(input('What was your discussion grade?: ')) # prompt grade 1
    quizGrade = int(input('What was your quiz grade?: ')) # prompt grade 2
    programGrade = int(input('What was your programming assignment grade?: ')) #prompt grade 3
    weightAvg.append (discussionGrade*0.20 + quizGrade*0.30 + programGrade*0.50) #calculate weighted average
    print('Your weighted grade point average is: ',weightAvg, '\n')`
```

#### The Output so far

```
Hey Rose ,please input the folowing grades:
What was your discussion grade?: 78
What was your quiz grade?: 88
What was your programming assignment grade?: 98
Your weighted grade point average is:  [91.0] 

Hey Dorothy ,please input the folowing grades:
What was your discussion grade?: 45
What was your quiz grade?: 99
What was your programming assignment grade?: 87
Your weighted grade point average is:  [82.2] 

Hey Sophia ,please input the folowing grades:
What was your discussion grade?: 67
What was your quiz grade?: 95
What was your programming assignment grade?: 77
Your weighted grade point average is:  [80.4] 

Hey Blanch ,please input the folowing grades:
What was your discussion grade?: 7
What was your quiz grade?: 45
What was your programming assignment grade?: 99
Your weighted grade point average is:  [64.4]
```

#### My Question

Essentially I want this output

```
print("The best student is (student name) with a score of (highest average)")
```

I have placed my first block in a function and tried to return weightAvg but im still not outputing what I would like.

Any help and explanation would be fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question. Please read [ask]. One problem with the question as currently formulated is that you say" im still not outputing what I would like." but never bother to inform those reading the question what output you would like. We could maybe guess -- but it would be better if you clearly communicate both the intended output and what you are seeing instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the averages outside the loop, to be able to have all of them once ended

Put the pairs `(avg, student)` in the loop, and at the end use `max` function, as we put the average value in the tuple, the items will be compared by that, if we had add `(student, avg)`, we would have had the max in term of lexicographical order (the nearest from end of alphabet

```
weightAvg = []
for student in students:
    print('Hey', student, ',please input the folowing grades:')
    discussionGrade = int(input('What was your discussion grade?: ')) 
    quizGrade = int(input('What was your quiz grade?: '))  
    programGrade = int(input('What was your programming assignment grade?: '))  
    avg = discussionGrade * 0.20 + quizGrade * 0.30 + programGrade * 0.50
    weightAvg.append((avg, student))  # calculate weighted average
    print('Your weighted grade point average is: ', avg, '\n')

best_avg, best_student = max(weightAvg)
print(f"The best student is {best_student} with a score of {best_avg}")
```